Centripetal force
Assume a rotating table which is at rest, a inextensible , massless thread it suspended below table , on the other end is a bob of some mass, now the system is at rest thread vertically downward with bob hanging, now the table starts rotating with some constant angular acceleration, i am the observer at ground watching the stuff and i noticed that bob is rotating as well as rising ( thread making some angle with vertical) now i can't understand why it is happening so which force is causing it to move out and above, don't include centrifugal force and also tell me why is it not rotating on its place, like why not on its own thread. Please answer as much conceptually and straightforward manner as you can, i am high school student looking for this answer for weeks

The tension from the thread is raising it. It changes when the bob deviates from vertical due to any deviation from vertical due to horizontal deviation of the table center as the table rotates. If everything were rotating perfectly it would not rise.  I will try to answer in more detail if I find the time later.

I am having a hard time following what the system is. Can you include a diagram?


I am the observer on the ground watching the stuff, and I noticed that bob
is rotating as well as rising (thread making some angle with
vertical)

Since the thread is at some angle from vertical, the suspension point of the thread must be displaced by some distance $x$ from the centre of the table. Similar problems to this usually have a mass on top of the table and a thread attached to the mass that passes through a hole in the table to a bob attached below. Since you have not mentioned a mass on top of the table or a hole in the table, I will assume the thread must be attached directly to the underside of the table. If the thread was located directly in the centre of the table, the bob would spin around an axis parallel to the suspended thread, and it would not rise because the increase in height ($h$) is due to the bob swinging out in an arc that takes it higher. If it doesn't swing out, it cannot rise.

Since the bob is moving in a circle, it requires a centrally directed force ($F_c$) to keep it moving in a circle at equilibrium. This centripetal force is provided by the horizontal component of the tension in the thread ($T$). If the thread was vertical, there would be no horizontal component to provide the centripetal force.
The tension force in the string has two components. One ($mg'$) balances the weight of the bob, and the other is an unbalanced force ($F_c$) that provides the inward-acting centripetal force.
Mathematically, the required centripetal force is equal to $m \omega^2 r$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the table and the upward reaction force is equal to $mg$. The centripetal force is $$F_c = \cos(\theta) T = m\omega^2 r$$ by simple geometry. If the length of the thread is $L$, then the height the bob rises is $$h = L-\sin(\theta) L.$$ We can also work out the tension force from the upward reaction component as $$T = \dfrac{mg}{\sin(\theta)}.$$ Equating this to the previous expression for $T$, we get $$\dfrac{mg}{\sin(\theta)} = m\omega^2 r$$ and solving it we get $$\theta = \sin^{-1}\left( \dfrac{g}{\omega^2 r}\right).$$ Substituting this expression for $\theta$ into the expression for $h$ gives us $$h= L - \dfrac{gL}{\omega^2 r}.$$

The thread can only provide tension force. This means that the thread can only apply a force to the bob parallel to itself. If the thread is hanging vertically, then it can only apply a vertical force to the bob. For another example of this, think of a pendulum. When the pendulum swings one way, the angle of the thread pulls the pendulum bob back towards the center position. When the pendulum is at its lowest position, there is no horizontal force because the thread is vertical.
When the table starts to rotate, the bob starts to move with it. By Newton's First Law, the bob wants to move in a straight line. It takes a centripetal force to push the bob into a circular path. When the thread is vertical, it cannot provide this force, so the bob moves outwards from the table.
As the bob moves outwards, the thread rotates away from horizontal. Since the tension force is now partially pointed towards the table, it can provide the centripetal force necessary to keep the bob in circular motion.
The upward motion of the bob is a consequence of the rotation of the thread away from vertical. The thread is inextensible and cannot stretch. When the bob moves away from the table, it must move up to keep the same distance from the thread's attachment point to the table.
